# Arduino program with C++ Visual studio Community 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, arduino

I have a school a project where I should create C++/CLI application with Visual Studio Community 2013, and this App uses an Arduino MEGA 2560 connected to a couple of pressure sensors.
I installed Visual Micro to Visual Studio, and I tried to run the Sample "Blink" program, but I have this problem:

[image]

Questions:

- How to solve this issue
- How can I communicate with the board from a C++/CLI interface
- I didn't find good resources concerning arduino programming using
  Visual Studio, if there's any, I'd appreciate it.

---

Comment: I don't have a big background on Arduino and VS but this page looks ok http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/VisualStudio

Comment: Thanks. I found this tutorial and it worked :) http://webtutsdepot.com/2010/05/01/arduino-visual-c-plus-plus-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks, I'm interested to start with Arduino programming too and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I found another useful tutorial, here it is:
https://www.electronicsblog.net/digital-voltmeter-arduino-ant-pc-visual-c-comunication-via-serial-port/

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused because you ticked "Tools>Visual Micro>Upload using programmer". The option relates to special hardware that you can purchase.

Un-tick the option for normal usb upload which does not require additional hardware. Read more [here](http://www.visualmicro.com/page/User-Guide.aspx?doc=Tools-Menu.html).

With the option ticked this is the same as using "File>Upload using programmer" in the Arduino ide